# Apach2 server only serves the index page of my site, why?

Tags: server, apache2, wordpress

## Background

I have WordPress site I am working on, It is on my local Ubuntu machine and is relatively simplistic. I'm using grunt to update the css.man and js.min files and using git for version control.

## Problem

When I try to access my site it works fine but if I click a link I get a `404` message.

I have added the following to my sites available

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ms.local

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /mnt/projects/mysite/html

    <Directory /mnt/projects/mysite/html>
    </Directory>
    
    LogLevel info
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ms.local.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ms.local.access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I have also created a symlink to this file from `sites-enabled`. I've added the site to my list of hosts also, like this

```
# Other sites
127.0.0.1   ms.local
```

The home page works perfectly apart from when I click an external link and get the 404 page.

The 404 page I get is the apache one with this line

> Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at ms.local Port 80

## Question

Why am I getting a 404 for every page that isn't my home and how do I stop it?

## Edit 1

I found the logs and see that it is looking in the wrong place for the other pages.

> [Tue Oct 13 13:51:56.104054 2015] [core:info] [pid 8253] [client 127.0.0.1:49174] AH00128: File does not exist: /mnt/projects/mysite/html/sitemap/, referer: http://ms.local/

what do I have to fix to get it to look in the right place WordPress or apache?

## Edit 2

I have gone into the WordPress admin and gone

> settings > permalinks

In here I set the permalink to default, this shows me a few more pages but with horrible urls.

Comment: Did you check the Apache error logs for this stuff?  That will be the best way to identify why it's 404-ing.

Comment: What 404 error do you get - Apache or Wordpress? What homepage do you see? The Apache or Wordpress homepage? If you edit the homepage, put in "TEST" on top of everything - do you see that?

Comment: yes its apache 404 and i can see edits i make to the home page

Comment: @JoeLloyd Did you look at the Apache error logs to make sure it's looking in the right place for the WordPress files (i.e. if the DocRoot is correct)

Comment: I'm normally a node server guy, Thomas where would I find these logs? etc/apache2... somewhere in there?

Comment: `/var/log/apache2/error.log` usually.

Comment: Did you restart the server?

Comment: my log file is not there (computer was used by someone else for a long time berfore me, mayber he disabled the logs...) & I've restarted the server several times.

Comment: Do you have other websites on that server and do they work? If somebody else has configured the server for his specific use (and maybe messed things up), is it an option to remove apache entirely, including all configuration (which can simply be backed up by `sudo cp -rp /etc/apache2 /etc-apache2-backup`) and reinstall? Tell us more about the setup, as this is relevant information and we cannot help you if you keep that from us.

Comment: I've added log info that I found as an edit in the question.